# How to get results from Get-ScheduledTask into PowerShell variables

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that starts a task on a remote server.  The task takes hours to run so I need to have a loop in my code to check the task every few minutes to see if it's still running before the script proceeds to the next step.  I tried running the following:

```
$svc_cred = Get-Credential -Credential <DOMAIN>\<ServiceAccount>
$global:Remote_session = New-PSSession -ComputerName <Server> -Credential $svc_cred 
Invoke-Command -Session $global:Remote_session -ScriptBlock {
  $results = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName  "Export_users" -TaskPath "\"
  Write-Output "Taskname: $results.TaskName"
  Write-Output "State:    $results.State"
}
```

But this produces the output:

```
Taskname: MSFT_ScheduledTask (TaskName = "Export_users", TaskPath = "\").TaskName
State:    MSFT_ScheduledTask (TaskName = "Export_users", TaskPath = "\").State
```

My desired outpout is:

```
Taskname: Export_users
State:    Running
```

How do I code this to allow access the script to check if State is equal to "Running"?

Comment: `"Taskname: $($results.TaskName)"` and `"State:   $($results.State)"` or even simpler, `$results | Select-Object TaskName, State`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I spent hours searching for the solution to this.  Where is this documented?

Comment: You mean documented the use of `$( ... )` ?

Comment: Yes.  I hit dozens of Google results and never saw that.

Comment: it's called [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the State property of a scheduled task on a while loop, like this:

```
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'SomeTaskName'
while ((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'SomeTaskName').State -ne 'Ready') {
    ##Wait a while
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Santiago Squarzon answered my question.

"Taskname: $($results.TaskName)" and "State:   $($results.State)" or even simpler, $results | Select-Object TaskName, State –
Santiago Squarzon